# Lock and erase options not appearing in Android Device manager

Tags: push-notifications, android-device-manager

My FairPhone appears in the [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager), its location is picked up, and I can ring it:

[image]

As you can see the separate *Lock* and *Erase* options do not appear as illustrated [in the help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?p=android_device_manager):

[image]

If I click the *Setup lock and erase* the website says it sent a setup notification. I do not see anything arriving on the phone.

On the phone I have turned on both *Remotely locate this device* and *Allow remote lock and erase* options [as described here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?p=android_device_manager).

In the play store, my device is set as 'Visible in menus'.

FWIW, I'm not signed in to Google+.

What am I missing?

Device: Android 4.2.2 'JellyBean MR2' / FairPhone 1.1 'Caju'. Not rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now the morning after the evening I wrote this question. My *Lock* and *Erase* settings are now automagically present in Android Device Manager.

I have not changed any settings or powered off the phone, it was just 'sleeping' last night.

So it looks like the Google servers needed some time to enable the settings.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Android Device Manager may not have administrator privileges. Go to:

```
Settings/Security/Device Administrators/
```

and make sure that Android Device Manager is checked. If it isn't, check it and agree to the popup. Then you should be able to enable it in the Google Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the lock and erase first! This just means clicking that button then setting up a service on Android to allow the Android Device manager to manage the device. The nexus 4 has this built in, so there's no need to set it up.

But as you have already clicked it, its a matter of checking if your phone has a good internet connection and can connect to Google. Also make sure that the Android Device manager is installed on the Android device in question

Comment: The app does not need to be installed. That is just to locate another device. The functionality is built into Google Play Services, so all Play Store certified devices 2.3(I believe) and up that are signed in to a Google account have this feature already.

Comment: I do not have a data connection active. I think that means that Google has to locate my phone by Wifi or GPS. Yesterday evening (at home, good Wifi) the location and test ring went fine, so the connection was OK. Just this morning (at the office, indoors, bad Wifi) the 'Ring' test from Device Manager failed, and Device manager could not locate me. I just reset the Wifi connection and now the ring comes through several minutes late and I am located. So your suggestion that a bad connection could be the reason is generally right, it just was not the case when I posted the question.